# Curl returns Invalid JSON error in a Jenkins Pipeline script but returns the expected response on a bash shell run or in a Jenkins Freestyle job

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, quotes, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a Jenkins Pipeline job for setting up AWS infrastructure using API calls to our in-house AWS CLI wrapper library. Running the raw bash scripts on a CentOS box or as a Jenkins Freestyle job runs fine. However, it fails in the context of a Pipeline job. I think that the quotes may need to be different for the Pipeline job but I am not sure how.

After further investigation, I found that the curl command returns the wrong response from the service when running the scripts within a Jenkins Pipeline job.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout code from Git'){
            steps {
                 echo "Checkout code from a GitHub repository"
                // Checkout code from a GitHub repository
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: false, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxx', url: 'git@github.com:bbc/repo.git']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Call our internal AWS CLI Wrapper System API to perform an ACTION on a specified ENVIRONMENT') {
            steps {

                script {
                    if("${params.ENVIRONMENT}" == 'int' && "${params.ACTION}" == 'create'){
                        echo "ENVIRONMENT=${params.ENVIRONMENT}, ACTION=${params.ACTION}"
                        echo ""
                        sh '''#!/bin/bash
                            # Create Neptune Cluster for the Int environment
                            cd blah-db
                            echo "Current working directory is $PWD"
                            CLOUD_FORMATION_FILE=$PWD/infrastructure/templates/neptune-cluster.json
                            echo "The CloudFormation file to operate on is $CLOUD_FORMATION_FILE"
                            echo "Running jq to transform the source CloudFormation file"
                            template=$(jq -M '.Parameters.Env.Default="int"' $CLOUD_FORMATION_FILE)
                            echo "Echoing the transformed CloudFormation file: \n$template"
                            echo "Running curl to make the http request to our internal AWS CLI Wrapper System"
                            curl -d "{\"aws_account\":  \"1111111111\", \"region\": \"us-east-1\", \"name_suffix\":  \"cluster\", \"template\": $template}" \
                            -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -H 'Accept: application/json' https://base.api.url/v1/services/blah-neptune/int/stacks \
                            --cert /path/to/client/certificate/client.crt --key /path/to/client/private-key/client.key
                            cd ..
                            pwd

                            # Set a timer to run for 300 seconds or 5 minutes to create a delay to allow for the Neptune Cluster to be fully provisioned first before adding instances to it.


                        '''

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The actual result that I get from making the API call:

```
{"error": "Invalid JSON. Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change the curl as following:

```
curl -d '{"aws_account":  "1111111111", "region": "us-east-1", "name_suffix":  "cluster", "template": $template}'
```

Or assign the whole cmd to a variable and print it out to see it's as your wanted or not.

```
cmd = '''#!/bin/bash
         cd blah-db
      ...
      '''

echo cmd // compare the output string to the cmd of freestyle job.

sh cmd
```

Comment: It did not work. I believe that I may have already tried this permutation of quoting while troubleshooting this initially. I have tried it again at your request and it did not work. Thank you very much. What could be the issue?

Comment: Okay, @yong, I will try this and revert in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that and it echoed the query back. The query looked like what I am passing in. For the Freestyle job, the query is run the same way I run it on a CentOS shell.